# What was the reason my process disappeared?

Tags: linux, process, gdb, signals, kill

I experienced a problem with my program at the customer site. It seems that the process is suddenly disappearing. I'm trying to find out why. Program is written in C++ and running on modern Linux systems (RHEL/Centos).

What I checked so far:

- program prints nothing on standard output or standard error, which it does when exception is thrown as my handler prints backtrace before aborting
- dmesg does not include anything meaningful (like OOM killer message or any other information the process was killed).

I have very limited access to the customer environment and I asked them to run a gdb and provide us with the log. The gdb script attaches to the process, catches throw, signals: SIGTERM SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2 SIGINT SIGSEGV SIGABRT SIGBUS SIGILL SIGQUIT as well puts a breakpoint on exit and _exit. The gdb log also does not contain any information regarding process catching any of these, nor receiving SIGKILL (and I believe this would normally be logged).

Any other ideas what else I could check?

Comment: What _does_ GDB print?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Literally nothing useful. I have enabled logging with 
`set logging file out.log` `set logging on` and the only thing found in the log is some sort of standard header with process id, executable path, cwd, cmdline, followed by the confirmation of the enabling catching signals and exceptions as well as placing the breakpoints. Then the log file ends.

Comment: Q: I assume you can't reproduce the problem?  Q: How frequently does it occur?  Daily? Hourly?  Once in a blue moon? ESSENTIAL QUESTIONS:  Q: When did it first start happening?  Q: "What changed" just before then?  ALSO: Q: Have you looked at the syslog?  Are there any syslog events correlated to the problem occurring?

Comment: @paulsm4 That situation happens when following a specific, known scenario. However it's only reproducible in the customer environment, with their data, which they cannot share with me as it contains sensitive information.
Thanks for the tip - I'll try request for syslog as well.

Comment: Don't forget the first two questions any help desk engineer asks: Q: When did it start?  Q: "What changed"?

Comment: If the program is terminating without GDB outputting anything, then one possibility is that something is killing the GDB process, too. The customer may need to enable *process accounting* or even *auditing* to see what’s happening.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That's an interesting clue. I did not consider it so far. Yet I checked and killing the gdb process gives me exactly the same log output. I'll investigate on that.